# Lagom microservice and Akka HTTP configuration location

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-http, lagom

I am using Lagom 1.4.6 and getting

```
akka.http.scaladsl.model.EntityStreamException: HTTP chunk size exceeds the configured limit of 1048576 bytes
```

with ServiceCall for a impl defined in a build.sbt.

Neither

```
akka.http.server.parsing.max-chunk-size = 10m
akka.http.client.parsing.max-chunk-size = 10m
```

nor

```
akka.http.host-connection-pool.client.parsing.max-chuck-size = 10m
```

in application.conf root or application.conf's

```
play { ... }
```

and

```
play { server { ... } }
```

block seem to do anything, I am still getting the same error message in Dev with the default 1M limit.

Where should [Akka HTTP configuration](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html) in a Lagom microservice go?

Comment: Which version of Lagom are you using? If you're using something before Lagom 1.4.x, it isn't using Akka HTTP by default.

Comment: Also, is the `application.conf` that you're adding those settings to in the `impl` resources directory?

Comment: Adding to what @erip said, the application.conf should be placed in resources directory. Take a look at this
https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-scala/tree/master/user-impl/src/main/resources

Comment: Lagom version is 1.4.6., I added it to the OP. application.conf is located at myservice-impl/src/main/resources/application.conf

Comment: @mpartan Could you make a reproducer? It's a bit hard to debug without any code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to prefix Akka-HTTP settings with `play.server`. The relevant section in the docs can be found [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsAkkaHttp).

It's important to note that in dev mode, a custom HTTP server is used so it may ignore these settings.

Comment: lagom.akka.dev-mode.config.akka.http.server.parsing.max-chunk-size = "10m" or play.server.akka.http.server.parsing.max-chunk-size = "10m" don't seem to have an effect in development environment.

Comment: @mpartan That's what the second line of my answer says.

Comment: Yes, that is why I'm referencing the lagom.akka.dev-mode.config.akka.http -config as well. I didn't find it in any official documentation on it, I took it from gitter. It doesn't resolve the issue though if I would like to develop against it, so would probably need to override in DevMode somehow.